# python 2.7 - how to print with utf-8 characters?

Tags: python, utf-8

i´m working with python version 2.7 and I need to know how to print utf-8 characters. Can anyone help me?
->I already tried putting # coding: iso-8859-1 -*- on top,
->using encode like print "nome do seu chápa".encode('iso-8859-1') also doesn't work and even
-> using print u"Nâo" doesn't work

Comment: Try: print u"Nâo".encode('utf-8')

Comment: tried it: just this, without any coding on top, gives me SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3'  on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

Comment: and with # coding: iso-8859-1 -*- or # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- it keeps bugging my special characters

Comment: Add the error message, please.

Comment: # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print u"Não".encode('utf-8') gives me NÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€ Ã¢â‚¬â„¢ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Â ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã¢â€žÂ¢ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã‚Â ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ã‚Â¬ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â‚¬Å¾Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€ Ã¢â‚¬â„¢ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ã‚Â¬Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã…Â¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¬ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â

Comment: and without the coding on top, it gives me SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file C:/Users/FábioPhillip/Desktop/UFRN 2014.2/topicos3_trabalho_remoto/PYTHONS DO TRABALHO/testeSaidaUtf8.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

Comment: Try other output encoding like latin1. It works for me.

Comment: Hi @FabioPhillipRochaMarques If one of the answers work for you, you can mark it as the answer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

A more complete response.

Strings have two types in Python 2, str and unicode.

When using str, you are using bytes so you can write them directly to files like stdout.

When using unicode, it has to be serialized or encoded to bytes before writing to files.

So, what happens here? `print "nome do seu chápa".encode('iso-8859-1')`

You have bytes but you try to encode them so Python 2 first decodes them behind your back and then encodes using the requested standard. This may work, if lucky, or produce gibberish.

Now, when doing the following: `print u"Nâo".encode('utf-8')`

You are telling Python 2 that you start with Unicode so then it will encode it without the problematic decode.

Python 3 solved this nastiness.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you put this line properly at the top of the document?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Also, I don't know is there any difference between iso- or utf in this particular problem, but I experienced some troubles with latin1 in my mother-language and some technical stuff, so I recommend the second one.

Comment: tried with both this and # coding: iso-8859-1 -*-, but neither worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer: my console needed to be restarted. I use Spyder(from Python x,y) for development and this error occcured, so beware.

UPDATE: Spyder console seems to suck, because to get it to work, I had to use string.encode('latin1') and (now here's the catch) OPEN A NEW CONSOLE! If I try to reuse my already open console, special characters just won't work.

Comment: oh wait, now It isn't working anymore. I guess I was lucky before

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1) Put on the first line of your code the line:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

2) Put u on the begining of very string with utf-8 characters:

```
 u'não vou esqueçer mais de usar o u no começo'
```